# Insert multiply rows into two tables with condition in one query

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `Products` and `PriceCategory`.

In `Products` there is (`UnitPrice`, `PriceCategoryID` [FK]).

In `PriceCategory` there is (`PriceCategoryID`,`PriceMin`, `PriceMax`).

I want to multiply insert all rows in table `PriceCategory`, and in table `Products` foreign key `PriceCategoryId` with condition that `UnitPrice` is between `PriceMin` and `PriceMax`.

Comment: Please add sample data from both table and your expected output.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question very well. Please add some sample data and expected output, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: There's no need to SHOUT, and you might want to add some formatting to that statement as well please.

Comment: Products(ProductId[PK],UnitPrice,ProductCategoryID[FK]) .PrtoductCategory(ProductCategoryID[PK],PriceMin,PriceMax).  I have to insert in ProductCategory all rows, and in Products UnitPrice and ProductCategoryID[FK].For example if UnitPrice is 5, and in Productcategory table : PriceMin=1, PriceMax=10, and PK PriceCategoryID=1,than in ProductTable in call for FK PriceCategoryID to be inserted 1.